# Java Decompiler Procyon throws NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javac, decompiling

I have a jar that I want to decompile (I have the source code, but I want to get the source code after the compile-time libraries have executed their... stuff)

(for example [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/), [java-oo](https://github.com/amelentev/java-oo) and runtime assertions for not-null-annotations)

So, I downloaded [Procyon](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/overview) (0.5.30) and tried to decompile the jar.

However, every time I run it, on the entire jar, or a single .class file, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/URLClassPath
    at com.strobel.assembler.metadata.ClasspathTypeLoader.<init>(ClasspathTypeLoader.java:66)
    at com.strobel.assembler.metadata.ClasspathTypeLoader.<init>(ClasspathTypeLoader.java:42)
    at com.strobel.assembler.InputTypeLoader.<init>(InputTypeLoader.java:45)
    at com.strobel.decompiler.DecompilerDriver.main(DecompilerDriver.java:96)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.URLClassPath
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

Googling "java decompiler procyon NoClassDefFoundError" or "java decompiler procyon sun.misc.URLClassPath" doesnt give me any useful results... apart from an issue on Luyten which is a GUI application that uses Procyon in the background, but that issue hasnt got any comments and is 24 days old.

The code is compiled with

```
- IntelliJ 2017.2
- javac version iDunno
- jdk-1.8.0_111
```

Comment: The stack trace looks like you are using Java 9, rather than `jdk-1.8.0_111`. It’s perfectly reasonable that the class `sun.misc.URLClassPath` does not exist anymore or at least that it will not be accessible from application code anymore. It has been said for decades that Java applications should not mess around with `sun.*` classes. Still, actually using `jdk-1.8.0_111` should solve the issue for the moment.

Comment: then I wonder why this says "1.8.0_111" http://i.imgur.com/qYcXpd0.png where would I double check that that is the correct version?

Comment: I have not much experience with IntelliJ, but IDEs usually have a project setting which determines the SDK to build the application, but also have *run* configurations, which default to the project setting, but may also get configured to use a  different execution environment.